# Избежать изменение esp в прологе функции с++

Tags: c++

В каких случаях в прологе функции на архитектуре x86 можно избежать изменения регистра esp?

Comment: думаю, нужно ещё и компилятор уточнить.

Но в любом случае, избежать изменения в прологе можно, если пролога не будет. Например, если функция заинлайнилась.

Comment: Компилятор clang плюсовый. Точно! есть же inline

Comment: Сдача экзамена онлайн через SO - это круто :)

Comment: У меня другой вопрос - почему возникают подобные вопросы?

Comment: Я еще не на экзамене)